# JobDetail JobDataMap vs Trigger JobDataMap for one job with multiple inputs

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have one job class that will get executed with different user inputs. I realize that I can specify the JobDataMap on both JobDetail and Trigger. So, I have two options in my case, if I understand it right:

(1) JobDataMap on JobDetail - when a user specifies new inputs and a schedule, create a new JobDetail with those inputs and create a new trigger. Then add the newly created jobDetail and trigger to the scheduler.

(2) JobDataMap on Trigger - when a user specifies new inputs and a schedule, create a new trigger with those inputs and add the trigger to the scheduler for the already added jobDetail.

Is there is a reason to prefer one option over the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From my personal experience, I have to say that we use the first approach (specify job params on `JobDetail`).

The main reason behing this decision is that is seems more simple and clean to understand and maintain.

- When a user schedules a job with specific parameters, we create a `JobDetail` with `JobDataMap` populated accordingly.
- The `Trigger` of this scheduled job may be fired many times, and we have to make sure that the parameters won't change and stay the same for all job executions.
- If a user wants to schedule a job of the same type with different parameters, a new `JobDetail` is being created and added to the scheduler.
- This way, we assume `JobDetail` to be our main "Job Definition" containing all the information needed to run the job (custom parameters, arguments etc) and we are leaving `Trigger` objects to deal with the execution times.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Thanks. That would be my preference too. I was wondering what would be the cases where one would prefer to add the job inputs to the Trigger. But this was helpful, thank you.